# PostgreSQL - CTE upsert returning modified rows

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1, common-table-expression, upsert

I've written an 'upsert' query using CTEs that looks something like this:

```
WITH
  new_data (id, value) AS (
    VALUES (1, 2), (3, 4), ...
  ),
  updated AS (
    UPDATE table t set
      value = t.value + new_data.value
    FROM new_data
    WHERE t.id = new_data.id
    RETURNING t.*
  )
INSERT INTO table (id, value)
  SELECT id, value
  FROM new_data
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM updated WHERE updated.id = new_data.id
  )
```

However I then need to work with the new values in my application, but this query will not return anything.  Adding `returning *` to the end of the insert will return all the rows that were inserted, but none of the rows that were updated.

So, the question is (how) can I extend this to return the rows that were updated AND the rows that were inserted?

*EDIT:* of course I could run this followed by a `SELECT` in a transaction, however I'm curious to see if there's a single-query way.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try something like:

```
WITH
  new_data (id, value) AS (
    VALUES (1, 2), (3, 4), ...
  ),
  updated AS (
    UPDATE table t set
      value = t.value + new_data.value
    FROM new_data
    WHERE t.id = new_data.id
    RETURNING t.*
  ),
  inserted as (
  INSERT INTO table (id, value)
  SELECT id, value
  FROM new_data
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM updated WHERE updated.id = new_data.id
  )
  RETURNING id, value)
SELECT id, value
FROM inserted 
UNION ALL
SELECT id, value
FROM updated
```

BTW this query is not a classical Postgres upsert. It will fail, if someone concurrently insert rows while `UPDATE table t` is going.

Comment: Thanks Igor, I did wonder about `UNION`, and that indeed seems to work.  Will this result in the 'updated' query being run twice, though?  (My understanding of CTEs is a little shaky, but I guess they're run once and remembered?)

Comment: Also, could you elaborate on your statement "BTW this query is not a classical Postgres upsert"?  This is the fashion of a lot of queries purported to be CTE-driven upserts.

Comment: @connec: "common tables" are run *once* and the result is materialized in an internal worktable.

Comment: @connec Read answers and comments to [`this`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109061/insert-on-duplicate-update-postgresql) questions. This CTE can fail in heavily concurrent environment. (but the chanses of failing are low)